# setting constraints in code doesn't produce the expected result

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

i'm trying to set a constraint in code and don't get the expected result.

I have a UIView container with 3 buttons (sub views) and i'm trying to set one's leading space to be the average of the other two's leading spaces (so it'll be in the middle, horizontally).
The numbers i get seem to be right when compared to the numbers i see on the storyboard when i place the 3 buttons in the position i want. 
I'm getting the leading space by their frame's x value (i've double checked that aligmentRectForFrame: gives the same results), and i average them.

I use:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *twitterConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:middleButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:average];
[twitterConstraint setPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired];
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[twitterConstraint]];
```

the basic functionality works i.e. if i put a number instead of the average i see results. I'm getting unexpected results with the current code. specifically, i'm getting the "middle button" on the right hand side of the other 2 buttons.

help!

idan

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following - what do you set average to be?

Comment: Have you forced layout before getting the existing button's frames? The values in the NIB may be very different from the values at run time. Anyway, querying frames to compute auto layout constants seems like a bad idea. (For example, leading is not always the same as the X coord. Also, if the buttons are not the same width, putting one's leading between the two others doesn't center it.) You can center a button with respect to a superview directly using the centerX attribute. You can create equal spaces with respect to siblings using spacer views whose widths are set equal.

Comment: the average is the other buttons leading space's average. 
@Ken - i did force leading space through interface builder on the button i'm interested in with a lower priority than the one i'm setting in code. all three buttons are the exact same size. i also double checked that the results i get using aligmentRectForFrame: are the same ones i get by using the x coordinate. also, the x values i get are equal to the leading spaces i see in Interface Builder. it looks to me that all the "components" of my calculations are as expected and even so, the final result isn't.

any other ideas?

Comment: What I meant by "force layout" is call `-layoutIfNeeded` on the containing view. Did you do that before inspecting frames?

Comment: that was it!
thanks Ken!

Comment: the main thing here is that i don't get the other buttons' correct x coordinates. i've put a button and got the x coordinates when the button is pressed, and got good results. i get the wrong values (the story board values, pre layout) when i try to get the x coordinates from viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidLayoutSubviews.
calling layoutIfNeeded solves it but it's not best practice performance wise. still trying to find the right place to call for the x values

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on why @Ken Thomases answer in comments works: Auto Layout first goes from subview-up to collect information, and then goes superview-down to set frames. So this code is sampling values of its subview frames, but at the time it is executed (in `updateConstraints` or `updateViewConstraints` or somewhere else) those views' frames haven't yet been set to their auto-layout-approved values. Unpredictable results can happen.

Calling -layoutIfNeeded on this view forces the Auto Layout engine to do this for the subviews--actaully do the layout work. So then sampling those subviews can work.

Unfortunately in this method, problems are created both sampling the frames to get information and calling layoutIfNeeded, which duplicates the expensive layout operations. As noted, it requires the buttons to be all the same size. Regardless, it's probably fine for this use case.

---

The way to set items to be evenly spaced using the native Auto Layout system (and allowing different-sized items) is spacer views. It's inelegant, but necessary. It can be done manually in IB, and here's how to do it with Visual Format Language:

```
NSMutableDictionary *autoLayoutDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSDictionary *setDictionary = @{
                                @"leftLabel":self.leftLabel,
                                @"middleLabel":self.middleLabel,
                                @"rightLabel":self.rightLabel
                                };
[autoLayoutDict setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:setDictionary];

int numberOfSpacerViewsRequired = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSpacerViewsRequired; i++) {

    UIView *spacerViewX = [[UIView alloc] init];
    spacerViewX.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    spacerViewX.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    spacerViewX.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSString *spacerViewKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"spacerView%i", i];
    [autoLayoutDict setObject:spacerViewX forKey:spacerViewKey];

    [self.view addSubview:spacerViewX];
}

NSArray *constraintsToAdd = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[leftLabel]-0-[spacerView0(spacerView1)]-0-[middleLabel]-0-[spacerView1(spacerView0)]-0-[rightLabel]"
                                        options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                        metrics:0
                                          views:autoLayoutDict];

[self.view addConstraints:constraintsToAdd];
```